# Issues with Turbo Rails routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Having a hard time understanding how Turbo works in Rails and why it is that I am getting redirected to a view that is not the dashboard  after I click in `<%= link_to dashboard_path %>`.

`dashboard_path` is a valid helper. Which I have verified by running rails routes and obtaining the following: `dashboard GET  /dashboard(.:format)   dashboard#index`

What I am getting is this:

[image]

But what I should be getting (the dashboard) is this:

[image]

Above all, notice the difference in the third column.

Following is how the views are rendered in the app, before getting to the view with `<%= link_to dashboard_path %>`:

`views/layout/applications` takes whatever is sent to it, after the user has signed-in and created a username, and adheres the sidebar to it so that they are displayed together.

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <% if controller_name == "usernames" %>
    <%= yield %>
  <% else %>
   <div class="container py-2 border border-dark">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row">
     <%= render "shared/sidebar" %>
     <%= yield %>
    </div>
   </div>
  <% end%>
      
<% else %>
 <%= yield %>
<% end%>
```

The `yield` statement in that case will refer to what is in `views/dashboard/index`. There what we have is this:

```
 <div class="mb-4">
    <%= link_to "Home", dashboard_path %>
  </div>
  <div class="mb-4"> 
    <%= render "shared/tweet_form" %>
  </div>
  <div id="tweets">
    <%= render partial: "tweets/tweet", collection: @tweets, as: :tweet_presenter %>
  </div>
</div>
 
<div class="col-3">
  <h4>This is the Dashboard third column</h4>
</div>
```

The `<%= render partial: "tweets/tweet", collection: @tweets, as: :tweet_presenter %>` in the previous view will render `views/tweets/tweet`, which, concisely has this structure:

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag dom_id(tweet_presenter.tweet) do %> 
…
    <%= link_to tweet_path(tweet_presenter.tweet), target: :_top do %>
          <%= image_tag "speech.png", size: "20x20", class: "me-1" %>
          <span>Replies<span>
        <% end %>
…
<% end %>
```

And, finally, when `link_to tweet_path(tweet_presenter.tweet)` is clicked this takes us to `views/tweets/show`

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag dom_id(@tweet) do %>
  <%= link_to dashboard_path do %>
     <%= image_tag "back-arrow.png", size: "30x30" %>
     <span>Tweet</span>
  <% end %>
  <%= @tweet.body %>
<% end %>

<div>
  <h4>This is the Show third column</h4>
</div>
```

At this point it is that clicking on `<%= link_to dashboard_path do %>` takes us to the troublesome view (the first screenshot) which seems to be a hybrid of `views/tweets/show` instead of the dashboard.

I have tried changing the link thus `<%= link_to :back do %>`, all to no avail: I obtain the same result. Don't know where to take it from here, because I do not understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```rb
<%= turbo_frame_tag dom_id(@tweet) do %>
  <%= link_to dashboard_path do %>
```

You're navigating inside of the tweet turbo frame. On the dashboard page, you're rendering:

```rb
<%= turbo_frame_tag dom_id(tweet_presenter.tweet) do %>
```

and it would match the current turbo frame, so the whole middle column is replaced only by a single tweet.

What you need is to move that link outside of the turbo frame or to specify `data-turbo-frame` attribute:
*https://turbo.hotwired.dev/reference/attributes*

```rb
<%= link_to dashboard_path, data: {turbo_frame: :_top} do %>
  ...
```

It might be useful to log the turbo frame header, so that you know when and what frame you're navigating:

```rb
# config/environments/development.rb

ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe("start_processing.action_controller") do |name, start, finish, id, payload|
  if payload[:headers]["Turbo-Frame"]
    Rails.logger.debug do
      "\e[0;35mTurbo-Frame:\e[0m #{payload[:headers]["Turbo-Frame"]}"
    end
  end
end
```

---

Note that `target: :_top` is for `<turbo-frame>` tag, on a link it's not a turbo attribute:
*https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attributes*

Comment: Thank you very much @Alex. That solved the issue, and your explanation made my understanding of the workings of the turbo_frame clearer.